# count word in textfile

Tags: python, string, file, python-3.x

I have a textfile that I wanna count the word "quack" in.

textfile named "quacker.txt" example:

This is the textfile **quack**.
Oh, and how **quack** did **quack** do in his exams back in 2009?\n Well, he passed with nine P grades and one B.\n He says that **quack** he wants to go to university in the\n future but decided to try and make a career on YouTube before that **Quack**....\n So, far, it’s going very **quack** well **Quack**!!!!

So here I want 7 as the output.

```
readf= open("quacker.txt", "r")
lst= []
for x in readf:
  lst.append(str(x).rstrip('\n'))
readf.close()
#above gives a list of each row.
cv=0
for i in lst:
  if "quack" in i.strip():
    cv+=1
```

above only works for one "quack" in the element of the list

Comment: is the data on one line or different lines?

Answer (score 2):

Well if the file isn't too long, you could try:

```
with open('quacker.txt') as f:
    text = f.read().lower() # make it all lowercase so the count works below
    quacks = text.count('quack')
```

As @PadraicCunningham mentioned in the comments, this would also count the 'quack' in
words like 'quacks' or 'quacking'. But if that's not an issue, then this is fine.

Comment: this would also count quacks etc.. and miss Quack

Comment: @PadraicCunningham True, I've drawn attention to this in the answer, in case it's an issue

Comment: well plus1 one anyway, in the simple case it will work, anything more advanced will need a bit more work.

Answer (score 1):

you're incrementing by one if the line contains the string, but what if the line has several occurrences of 'quack'?

try:

```
for line in lst:
    for word in line.split():
        if 'quack' in word:
            cv+=1
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to lower, strip and split to get an accurate count:

```
from string import punctuation
with open("test.txt") as f:
    quacks = sum(word.lower().strip(punctuation) == "quack"
                  for line in f for word in line.split())
    print(quacks)
7
```

You need to split each word in the file into individual words or you will get False positives using in or count. `word.lower().strip(punctuation)` lowers each word and removes any punctuation, sum will sum all the times `word.lower().strip(punctuation) == "quack"` is True.

In your own code `x` is already a string so calling `str(x)...` is unnecessary, you could also just check each line the first time you iterate, there is no need to add the strings to a list and then iterate a second time. Why you only get one returned is most like because all the data is actually on a single line, you are also comparing `quack` to `Quack` which will not work, you need to lower the string.